# Special Characters In Webapp being saved differently

Tags: java, html, spring, unicode

I'm creating a webapp using Spring MVC and some of the information I'm pulling is from a Database, so it was edited elsewhere. When I import some have, what I consider, special characters, such as

`“_blank”`

as opposed to using the standard keyboard

`"_blank"`.

When I display this on my website textarea, it displays fine, but when I attempt to save it back into the string when submitting the form in the spring textArea, the string now has ? where the 'special' characters were. They were obviously imported into a String fine, but somewhere in the save process it's not allowing it as a special character. Any idea what is causing this or why?

Comment: What do you mean by 'save it', a database?

Comment: Edited above, but no, not into the database, but back into the string when I submit the web form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a character encoding problem. Try setting the character set of the page containing the form to UTF-8.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```